# display per day's rows of record with respective timestamp - PHP

Tags: php, timestamp

I've an associative array. In that array one of the array element is timestamp. I'm logging data from a device for each every minute of a day. I need to display the data in a table. First row of table show start date with start time and start date with end time. Second row of table show next day of data with start time and end time.. and so on. Yes table look like a trip sheet. I'm getting the data from an API. If i pass an date and time in the API, i will get the data for the respective timestamp. For example if pass $srtttime= '2016-05-03 00:00:00' $edtime= '2016-05-04 23:59:59' to the API i will get the data for the date 2016-05-03 and time between '00:00:00' to '23:59:59'. I able to create a row for one date. Below code display a  row of record, here i takes the first and last record. See the below image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm6vL.png)

```
$i=0;
    $len=0;
    $len=count($json_output);
    echo "<center><table border='1'></center>";
    echo '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Start Time</th><th>Origin Address</th><th>End Time</th><th>Destination Address</th></tr>';
        foreach($json_output as $value)
        {
            if($i==0)
                {
                    $STR_TIME=$value['rtctime'];
                    $DTE=substr($STR_TIME,0,10);
                    $STR_TIME=substr($STR_TIME,11,8);
                    $LAT_S=$value['latitude'];  
                    $LON_S=$value['longitude'];
                    $ST_ADDR=getaddress($LAT_S,$LON_S);
                }
            elseif($i==$len-1)
                {
                    $EN_TIME=$value['rtctime'];
                    $EN_TIME=substr($EN_TIME,11,8);
                    $LAT_E=$value['latitude'];  
                    $LON_E=$value['longitude'];
                    $EN_ADDR=getaddress($LAT_E,$LON_E);
                }
                $i++;

        }
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$DTE</td>";
        echo "<td>$STR_TIME</td>";
        echo "<td>$ST_ADDR</td>";
        echo "<td>$EN_TIME</td>";
        echo "<td>$EN_ADDR</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
```

The problem i don't know how to show rows if i pass more than one days timestamp to API i.e. $strttime= '2016-05-03 00:00:00' $edtime= '2016-05-07 23:59:59' here i passing 4 days between start day 03-05-2016 to end day 07-05-2016.Here i have to show four rows. I have tried a lot, but i cannot get it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need the foreach loop if you only want the first and last records.  Your code should be

```
// Take out first element of array
$str_time = array_shift($json_output);

// Take last element of array
$end_time = array_pop($json_output);

$STR_TIME=$str_time['rtctime'];
$DTE=substr($STR_TIME,0,10);
$STR_TIME=substr($STR_TIME,11,8);
$LAT_S=$str_time['latitude'];  
$LON_S=$str_time['longitude'];
$ST_ADDR=getaddress($LAT_S,$LON_S);

$EN_TIME=$end_time['rtctime'];
$EN_TIME=substr($EN_TIME,11,8);
$LAT_E=$end_time['latitude'];  
$LON_E=$end_time['longitude'];
$EN_ADDR=getaddress($LAT_E,$LON_E);

echo "<center><table border='1'>";
echo '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Start Time</th><th>Origin Address</th><th>End Time</th><th>Destination Address</th></tr>';
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$DTE</td>";
echo "<td>$STR_TIME</td>";
echo "<td>$ST_ADDR</td>";
echo "<td>$EN_TIME</td>";
echo "<td>$EN_ADDR</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</center>";
```

You also had an html markup error with the center end tag.

Comment: Thank you. Your code helps me to fetch first and last record.